# Accordion - add arrow to each nav item?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have implemented this accordions script under [What We Do](http://chesapeakepro.missionmedia.net/about)

I need to add up and down arrows to each nav item as seen in [this pic](http://techavid.com/chesa_pro_about.jpg).  Where and how do I code in the two states(inactive arrow & active arrow) into the jQuery.  Im thinking I need to code this into the jQuery?

Comment: And what mark-up are you working with? What have you tried? Posting the code *here* helps, and a live demo on a site like [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) also helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some simple CSS classes, since the `a`'s have different classes when they are opened:

`toggler toggler-closed` and `toggler toggler-opened`

```
.toggler.toggler-opened {
    /* a background image on the right side with arrow down? */
}

.toggler.toggler-closed {
    /* a background image on the right side with arrow to the right? */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems relatively simple, though I'm perhaps using a little too much jQuery:

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.toggler').each(function(){
            $('<span></span>').appendTo($(this));
        });
        $('.toggler-closed > span').text('▶');
        $('.toggler-opened > span').text('▼');
    });
```

#### css:

```
.toggler span {
  float: right;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```