# Adding arrow to accordion

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, css

Using David's answer here:

[Accordion - add arrow to each nav item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239439/accordion-add-arrow-to-each-nav-item/4239506#4239506)

on my accordion here:

[Error Help::Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl00' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459668/error-helpmultiple-controls-with-the-same-id-ctl00-were-found-findcontrol-re)

The arrows won't show..what's wrong?

Comment: are you dynamically changing the classes depending on whether the accordion is expanded or not? It's really the resultant html that needs scrutiny

Comment: No I am not. Plz check my code..Thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459668/error-helpmultiple-controls-with-the-same-id-ctl00-were-found-findcontrol-re

Comment: the link you provided to the method David use to add arrows is dependant on classes changing in accordance to the state of the accordion. I'm not a .net guy which is why I want to see the html that is output. This way I can see if there is anything already present we can use as an identifier or how to format the javascript to make an identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a guess at how the accordion will work - here is some code that should work

**jQuery:**

```
function checkVisibility() {
  $('.accordionHeader.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
  $('.toggler .accordionContent:visible').each(function(){
    $(this).prev('.accordionHeader').addClass('expanded');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  checkVisibility();
  $('.toggler .accordionHeader').not('.expanded').click(checkVisibility());
});
```

**css:**

```
.toggler .accordionHeader {
  background:url(* add a path to an arrow here *) no-repeat left center transparent;
  }

.toggler .expanded {
      background-image:url(* add a path to alternate arrow here *);
    }
```

**EDIT - Alternative**

Here I have modified the script in the link you provided. Use the same css from the link provided (untested) - not what I have entered above. Previous option is better imo...

```
function checkVisibility(){
  $('.accordionHeader.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
  $('.accordionHeader > span').text('▶');
  $('.toggler .accordionContent:visible').each(function(){
    $(this).prev('.accordionHeader').addClass('expanded').find('span').text('▼');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordionHeader').each(function(){
        $('<span></span>').appendTo($(this));
    });
  $('.toggler .accordionHeader').not('.expanded').click(checkVisibility());
});
```